# Ionic 3 input set not firing when the value is changed inside onKeyboardShow function

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I have a Component with two `<ion-fab>` buttons that I want to move whenever I change the value of a variable called `alturaTeclado: number`. Here is the relevant part of the component:

```
import {Keyboard} from "@ionic-native/keyboard";
...

@Component({
    selector: 'page-login',
    templateUrl: 'login.html'
})
export class LoginPage {
    ...
    alturaTeclado: number = 0;

    constructor(
    ...
    private keyboard: Keyboard) {

        // setTimeout(()=>{
        //     this.alturaTeclado = 249;
        // },1000);

        this.keyboard.onKeyboardShow().subscribe(eventoTeclado => {
            // eventoTeclado.keyboardHeight is 249 when opened
            this.alturaTeclado = eventoTeclado.keyboardHeight;
            console.log('ABRIR teclado altura resultado', this.alturaTeclado);
        });

        this.keyboard.onKeyboardHide().subscribe(eventoTeclado => {
            console.log('Evento teclaod ', eventoTeclado);
            this.alturaTeclado = 0;
            console.log('CERRAR teclado altura resultado', this.alturaTeclado);
        });
    }

    moverBotones() {
        console.log('mover botones');
        if (!this.alturaTeclado) {
            this.alturaTeclado = 249;
        } else {
            this.alturaTeclado = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

This is what the HTML looks like:

```
<ion-fab bottom left fabDeslizante [alturaTeclado]="alturaTeclado">
    <button type="button" ion-fab color="primary" >
        <ion-icon name="ios-undo"></ion-icon>
    </button>
</ion-fab>
```

fabDeslizante is a Directive I've created to achieve that:

```
@Directive({
    selector: '[fabDeslizante]'
})
export class FabDeslizanteDirective implements OnInit, OnChanges {

    altura: number = 0;

    constructor(private el: ElementRef) {
    }

    @Input() set alturaTeclado(altTeclado: number) {
        console.log('Altura anterior', this.altura);
        console.log('Altura teclado', altTeclado);
        this.altura = altTeclado;
        this.el.nativeElement.style.transform = 'translate3d(0, -' + this.altura + 'px, 0)';
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.el.nativeElement.style.transitionDuration =  '0.3s';
    }

    ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
        console.log('Cambios ', changes);
    }
}
```

The problem is that the `@Input() set alturaTeclado(altTeclado: number)` function doesn't fire when the keyboard opens. Console shows the message of the component properly with the correct value of `this.alturaTeclado` (249 in this case) but not the messages from the Directive. After opening the keyboard, if I click anywhere it suddenly shows Directive messages and the button moves.

If I change the value of `this.alturaTeclado` from `moverBotones()` function, or from the commented `setTimeout`, it works well.

Keyboard plugin:

```
cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.1.2 "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard"
```

Window is not resizing because I've changed `windowSoftInputMode`:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the code run inside `onKeyboardShow()` callback is outside Angular Zone and it doesn't update the UI and this is the cause of not firing `@Input() set alturaTeclado(altTeclado: number)` (even if the value of `this.alturaTeclado` is changing)

In case any other finds it useful, you can check if your code is in Zone importing NgZone:

```
import {NgZone} from '@angular/core';
```

and runnning:

```
NgZone.isInAngularZone()
```

In my example:

```
this.keyboard.onKeyboardShow().subscribe(eventoTeclado => {
    console.log('angular zone', NgZone.isInAngularZone());
    this.alturaTeclado = eventoTeclado.keyboardHeight;
    console.log('ABRIR teclado altura resultado', this.alturaTeclado);
});
```

It prints:

```
angular zone false
```

To solve my problem I just added the run() method from NgZone:

```
constructor(
    ...
    private keyboard: Keyboard,
    public zone: NgZone) {
        ...
    }
...
)

this.keyboard.onKeyboardShow().subscribe(eventoTeclado => {
    console.log('angular zone', NgZone.isInAngularZone());
    this.zone.run(() => {
        console.log('angular zone 2', NgZone.isInAngularZone());
        this.alturaTeclado = eventoTeclado.keyboardHeight;
    });
});
```

It works as I wanted and it prints:

```
angular zone false
angular zone 2 true
```

[Official docs for NgZone](https://angular.io/api/core/NgZone)

Hope it helps someone else